# NESTJS Get the execution context within the exception filter

Tags: nestjs

I store user identification data in the execution context with my authentication guard. I would like to retrieve this context in the exception filter so I can set sentry metadata from user identification data. Exception filter however receives ArgumentsHost from the constructor, not the execution context where user identification data are stored. Can I somehow retrieve the execution context within the exception filter?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried it like it is specified in the [docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/exception-filters#exception-filters-1)?

```js
@Catch(HttpException)
export class HttpExceptionFilter implements ExceptionFilter {
  catch(exception: HttpException, host: ArgumentsHost) {
    const ctx = host.switchToHttp()
    let request = ctx.getRequest<Request>()
    
    /* ... */
  }
}
```

Comment: const ctx = host.switchToHttp() is not type of ExecutionContext but HttpArgumentsHost. The reason, why we store user identification data, is that our server uses graphql, graphql subscriptions, HTTP with Fastify adapter and those protocols does not share request object. However, they share execution context object

Comment: ok my bad. I don't think that it is possible to get execution context inside an Exception  Handler :/

Answer (score 0):

So I found that identification data are in the execution context only for a short time being and vanish when accessed with paramDecorator. So I store my identification data (ReqUser) in a request object specific to each context type. Now I access those contexts with help of the Helper class from guards, interceptors, and exception filters.

```js
export class Helpers {
  public static getReqUserDestinationFromHost(host: ArgumentsHost): Record<string, unknown> {
    switch (host.getType<ContextType | 'graphql'>()) {
      case RequestType.HTTP:
        return host.switchToHttp().getRequest();
      case RequestType.GRAPHQL:
        return GqlArgumentsHost.create(host).getArgByIndex(2);
      case RequestType.WEB_SOCKET:
        throw new NotImplementedException('WEB_SOCKET ReqUser destination is not reachable');
      case RequestType.RPC:
        throw new NotImplementedException('RPC ReqUser destination is not reachable');
    }
    throw new NotImplementedException('Unable to identify ReqUser destination');
  }

  public static getReqUserDestinationFromContext(
    context: ExecutionContext
  ): Record<string, unknown> {
    switch (context.getType<ContextType | 'graphql'>()) {
      case RequestType.HTTP:
        return context.switchToHttp().getRequest();
      case RequestType.GRAPHQL:
        return context.getArgByIndex(2);
      case RequestType.WEB_SOCKET:
        throw new NotImplementedException('WEB_SOCKET ReqUser destination is not reachable');
      case RequestType.RPC:
        throw new NotImplementedException('RPC ReqUser destination is not reachable');
    }
    throw new NotImplementedException('Unable to identify ReqUser destination');
  }
}
```